# Commit Existing Transaction and Open new transaction - Spring Boot @Transactional

Tags: spring-boot, spring-transactions, distributed-transactions, atomikos

I have a requirement where I have to read a message from Queue and update the database in one transaction. Then in another transaction, read the same record from database, process it and save the status to processed.

Since I am updating the same record in new transaction, the new transaction gets committed, but the outer transaction rollbacks complaining the record state has changed.

I am wondering how do I commit that first update to table and then the next transaction uses the updated record. In general, both transaction should run independent of each other.

```
   public class MessageReader {

        @JmsListener(destination = "${queue.name}", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
        @Transactional
        public void onMessageReceived(@Payload Message message) {
            log.info("Message to be processed: {}", situationMessage);
            //update table record to "in progress"
            try {
                //call to message processor
                messageProcessor.process(message);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


public class MessageProcessor {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void process(Message message) {
        //process the message
        //update the same table record to "completed".
    }
}
```

Comment: Updating the record from first transaction without committing it to database does not make sense. If refactoring is an option , move the first txn code logic to a method in `MessageProcessor` and annotate the same with `@Transactional`. `@Transactional`  may be removed from `onMessageReceived()` . This way first create runs in a txn and once that is committed , the update runs in a different txn.

Comment: We want message reading & database update to happen in one transaction, so that if DB update fails, the queue would rollback. If I move the db update to different method, then only db update will be in txn and message reading from the queue would not be involved in the txn.

Comment: Then remove `(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` from `process()`. No new txn will be started in between . The default propogation is `REQUIRED` and the method call takes part in the existing txn

Comment: there are two db updates happening here. The first update for "in progress" should happen along with queue in one txn. The second update to completed should happen in separate txn so that if any exception occurs during processing should leave the record in "in progress" status. I used new txn to do that second update so that that will not rollback the first update.

Comment: and in the process you are modifying the state of the first txn isn't it ? If I understand correctly , message and "in progress" should happen in txn1 and that should commit . process and "completed" in second txn2 . They shouldn't be nested

Comment: yes, change the state of the same record (which we updated to "in progress" in jms listener method) to completed in process method. you are right, I want both txn to run independently and not nested. I don't know how to end the first txn and call the process method from jms listener method so that it creates a new txn.

Comment: As stated in my first comment . `onMessageReceived()` can be modified to call two different methods for "in progress" and "complete" , both having its own txns. eg:  `@Transactional onMessageReceived()` calling `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) updateStatus("In Progress")` and then `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) updateStatus("Completed")`

Comment: yes, that will solve my problem. thanks for the hanging in so far! one point to note, the queue txn will be open till the `updatestatus("Completed")` txn gets completed. Is there anyway to close it before starting `process()` ?

Comment: do you need that txn now ? If not , you may remove the `@Transactional` annotation from that method

Comment: how do we rollback the message back to queue, if the db update fails? since I have `@Transactional` on listener, if I throw exception from `updateStatus('in progress')` then the message will rollback to queue.

Comment: The scope of the txn started with `onMessageReceived()` is the start to end of that method.